# Why does SCOPE_IDENTITY() return -1?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have written this Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [cairs].[sp_SaveR]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@fname  nvarchar(50),
@lname  nvarchar(50),
@mname  nchar(10),
@sigDate    date        
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    insert into tUser
(fname,
lname,
mname,
sigDate
 )
values
(
@fname,
@lname,
@mname,
@sigDate)

select SCOPE_IDENTITY()

END
```

This is the c# code I use to connect to it:

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cCon.getConn()))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            conn.Open();

            cmd.CommandText = "sp_SaveR";                                           
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fname", fName));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lname", lName));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@mname", mName));                       
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sigDate", sigDate));

            int userID =  (int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw(ex);
}
```

My `userID` is always returning -1, even though the records are successfully inserted into the DB table. Why does this happen?

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` seems like the wrong method to use here - surely you're wanting to consume the results of the final query, so `ExecuteReader` (or more likely, `ExecuteScalar`) would seem appropriate. Also, not relevant to your current problem, but you should avoid using the `sp_` prefix - it's reserved by Microsoft for their system procedures.

Comment: That is because you are getting the return value from your procedure. You should use an OUTPUT variable. As a side note, you should consider not using the sp_ prefix (or even better no prefix at all). http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: thank you both! i had no idea about the sp, i thought it was the norm naming for stored procedures :-/

Comment: Personally I abhor prefixes. It harkens back to the days of VB6 when you prefixed variables with the datatype. Was a real pain to deal with when you need to change the datatype. Same concept in sql server.

Comment: No, ideally you don't use any prefixes in naming your SQL objects - certainly not to identify their type - except for tables and views, which *ought* to be treated as if they're the same things - there's no ambiguity in the syntax such that you cannot identify the type of an object simply by its position within the query.

Comment: prefixes aren't that bad all the time.. we have a lot of generated procs and some custom procs.. both are similar name wise, just the generated ones start `gsp_` and custom procs are `usp_`  makes finding the custom procs a lot easier in management studio and allows our custom edmx builder to ignore the generated procs when importing functions.  And don't ask me why we use entity framework and also generate crud procs.. I wasnt here for that decision making.

Comment: i've added "OUTPUT" variable, and changed ExecuteNonQuery to ExecuteReader. That did it. thank you all!

Comment: If you aren't returning a dataset you can stick with the `ExecuteNonQuery`

Comment: Interesting exception handler.

Comment: As another note you may want to look at using an `OUTPUT` clause instead of `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Answer (score 3):

`ExecuteNonQuery` discards the result set. The number it returns is usually the number of rows affected, but it isn't something you can really rely on. In your case, it returns -1 because you're executing a stored procedure, it would return 1 if you inlined the SQL.

You want to use `ExecuteScalar` instead, which reads the first column from the first row in the first result set.

Comment: Another option would be to add an output parameter to the proc.

Answer (score 0):

This is working as designed.  The return value is the number of modified rows.  If you are calling a stored proc or selecting data the value will be -1.

**From MSDN...**

[SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `output` parameter to retrive id like as below.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [cairs].[sp_SaveR]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@fname  nvarchar(50),
@lname  nvarchar(50),
@mname  nchar(10),
@sigDate    date,
@NewId int OUTPUT        
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
insert into tUser
(fname,
lname,
mname,
sigDate
)
values
(
@fname,
@lname,
@mname,
@sigDate)

select @NewId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

END
```

In C#:

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cCon.getConn()))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            conn.Open();

            cmd.CommandText = "sp_SaveR";                                           
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fname", fName));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lname", lName));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@mname", mName));                       
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sigDate", sigDate));
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@NewId", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int userId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@NewId"].Value);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw(ex);
}
```